# Migrating website to subfolder in another domain

Tags: migration, subdirectory

I've a old site : `site1.com` but I want to move it to a folder in another site: `site2.com`.

So `site1.com/about.htm` content should be accessible as `site2.com/new/about.htm`.

Beyond doing a 301/302 I think I'd need to add content of *robots.txt* from `site1.com` into `site2.com`'s.
Similarly `site1.com` sitemap URLs would need to be changed and should appear below `site2.com`'s.

Is there a checklist for doing such migration?

Comment: Redirect 301 is your friend ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to:

1. List all URLs from your old domain
2. List all new URLs from your new domain
3. Create a *.htaccess* file and use the structure:

`Redirect 301 /old-page.htm http://www.newdomain.com/folder/new-page.htm`